# NodeJS - Deploy socket server in Jelastic

Tags: node.js, sockets, jelastic

I have a socket server that I want to deploy in my `Jelastic` `NodeJS` setup. It is made of 2 files, being `server.js` the main file, the one started/opened by node, and `worker.js` the file opened as a child process by the server when required (each child handles a socket).

I never deployed a project via Jelastic or any other cloud PaaS/hosting. How should I proceed to do this?

I know that I have to write the package.json, but that's all I know.

So far, this is what I've got:

```
//package.json
{
  "name": "Myserver",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My Server",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "microtime": ">=1.2.0",
    "microseconds": ">=0.0.2",
    "mysql": ">=2.5.4",
    "point-in-polygon": ">=0.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "Magister"
}
```

I searched on their docs but all they have is how to deploy a WEB application, but my server is not web-related, so that information is not relevant.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a public IP? Most likely WebSocket app won't work behind the proxy so far

Comment: Yes, there is a public IP. The problem is that I can't even run/execute the script. Perhaps there are some environment variables that I am not aware of or something. All I know is that Jelastic uses Openshift technology to run NodeJS